# React-Dom issue after upgrading to next 12

Tags: next.js, react-dom, react-dom-server

I have upgraded my large project form Next 10 to Next 12, and I am getting this error:

```
app_container  | Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
app_container  |     at renderElement (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6043:9)
app_container  |     at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
app_container  |     at renderNodeDestructive (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
app_container  |     at renderForwardRef (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5859:5)
app_container  |     at renderElement (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6005:11)
app_container  |     at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
app_container  |     at renderNodeDestructive (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
app_container  |     at renderNode (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
app_container  |     at renderHostElement (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5642:3)
app_container  |     at renderElement (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5952:5)
```

It looks like I have an issue with the react-dom, and I cannot find exactly where this error occurs. Since my code-base is quite large it is very difficult to pinpoint exactly where the problem is originated.

**How do I troubleshoot this problem?**
I have seen threads where this error occurs, and it is about deconstructing object in imports. But iff that is the case in my project I cannot find it, since my project is large. How can I find where this problem is in the code?

I am including my package.json, in case the problem could be there.

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn && TSC_NONPOLLING_WATCHER=1 NODE_ENV=development nodemon",
    "generate": "graphql-codegen",
    "build": "next build && tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js",
    "build:preprod": "PORT=3332 next build && tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "start:preprod": "PORT=3332 NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .tsx --ext .ts .",
    "clean": "npx rimraf node_modules && npx rimraf .next"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.15",
    "@apollo/react-common": "^3.1.4",
    "@apollo/react-components": "^4.0.0",
    "@apollo/react-hoc": "^4.0.0",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@codemirror/basic-setup": "^0.18.2",
    "@codemirror/commands": "^0.18.3",
    "@codemirror/gutter": "^0.18.4",
    "@codemirror/lang-javascript": "^0.18.0",
    "@codemirror/lang-markdown": "^0.18.4",
    "@codemirror/state": "^0.18.7",
    "@codemirror/theme-one-dark": "^0.18.1",
    "@codemirror/view": "^0.18.17",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.2.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "^2.1.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^2.1.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.1.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-query": "^3.5.8",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-define": "^2.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "lang-papershive": "^0.1.16",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "12",
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "next-plugin-custom-babel-config": "^1.0.5",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "pdfjs": "^2.4.7",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.16.105",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-fast-compare": "^3.2.0",
    "react-mathjax": "^1.0.1",
    "react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-querybuilder": "^5.1.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "v6.0.0-rc.1",
    "vue": "3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11 ",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "prettier": "^2.4.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "proxy": "localhost:3001"
}
```